# How does subscription work when I upgrade to a higher subscription before my current subscription ends?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am implementing in-app purchase in my application.

When the user purchases a subscription, it allows the user to have access to the subscription until the end of the current billing cycle, at which point of time the subscription is automatically renewed. This repeats until the subscription is cancelled by the user.

For example, if a user purchases a monthly subscription on jan 1st and upgrade it on the Jan 15th day of the cycle to 3 months subscription, Google Play will consider the 1st subscription valid until the end of the  Jan month (30th day) (or other day, depending on the month).and my (2nd) upgraded  3 months subscription started from Jan 15th and ends after 3 months of purchase date i.e (April 15th)...

But did u observe I lost 15 days of my subscription in this cycle, because google allows multiple subscriptions at a time. How can I update my upgraded subscription dates?

**I need to start my 2nd subscription plan right after the end of the 1st Subscription period.**

**Can the 1st subscription be cancelled by any method when I upgrade to another subscription?**

Here is my Google Developer API ressponse:

```
{
    "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
    "startTimeMillis": "1535366609722",
    "expiryTimeMillis": "1535368525233",
    "autoRenewing": true,
    "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
    "priceAmountMicros": "2100000000",
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "developerPayload": "",
    "paymentState": 1,
    "orderId": "GPA.3322-1385-5105-0000..0",
    "purchaseType": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will first answer your question and then explain.

**I need to start my 2nd subscription plan right after the end of the 1st Subscription period.**

> You can not stop the user from upgrading/downgrading the subscription. However, the price is prorated according to settings.

This is the excerpt from Android Developer. To understand how this works you need to read [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#set-proration-mode). Google has explained proration modes with examples. Follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#set-proration-mode) to get the clear idea.

> The following table lists all of the proration modes.
>
> IMMEDIATE_WITH_TIME_PRORATION Replacement takes effect immediately,
>   and the new expiration time will be prorated and credited or charged
>   to the user. This is the current default behavior.
>   IMMEDIATE_AND_CHARGE_PRORATED_PRICE   Replacement takes effect
>   immediately, and the billing cycle remains the same. The price for the
>   remaining period will be charged. Note: This option is only available
>   for subscription upgrade.
>
> IMMEDIATE_WITHOUT_PRORATION   Replacement takes effect immediately, and
>   the new price will be charged on next recurrence time. The billing
>   cycle stays the same.